# How to check on windows whether my long-time program closed automatically or manually by others?

Tags: linux, windows

I'm running my own daily-running long-time program on some public computer on windows(win10).And today it closed with no reason at some time.I've checked logs, my program seems running fine.

So now I have no idea what's is going on?I'm a bit familiar on linux maintenance but not on windows. Is there any clues on windows as if `/var/log/message` or `/var/log/cron` on linux?If there is, where and how to check?
Even more, maybe my program runs into some coredump, is there anything on windows like `/var/spool/abrt/coredump` on linux?

Now I'm strongly surspect someone closed my program manually, but I can't prove that.

Comment: 3221225786 seems meanning `control+C`. But who sends `control+C` and how?Could I make it out?

Comment: Windows has an event log.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, one could account for any possible predictable way of the program ending by handling each scenario and writing information to disk of the reason it's ending.

At a later time, if we find the program has ended and no information was written, then either we've failed to predict possible ways for the program to end or it was ended by a hard crash (e.g. desktop computer loses wall power).

If we've accounted for every possible scenario, then we should assume that when we find an absence of written closure information then the program was ended by hard crash. There are scenarios where a user could force a program to close in such a way without a hard crash actually occurring. In either case, I'd expect something to appear in the Windows event logs (Win+X, V, WindowsLogs->Application).

What sort of program is it? Console program? WinForms application? Windows Service?

Comment: Additionally, one way to preliminarily investigate could be to have your program record its state periodically, say every two minutes, along with the names of every open window and every process running. Could provide clues towards the timing and cause.

Comment: Console program actually